Awssdk in c++ ignores Legal Hold Locks of the MinIO s3 store
I have a object on a MinIO s3 Object Store and want to lock it with a Legal Hold so that I cannot overwrite it in c++.
I set the Legal Hold like that:
    Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectLegalHoldRequest request;
    request.SetBucket(bucketName);
    request.SetKey(manag_file_name);
    Aws::S3::Model::ObjectLockLegalHold lock;
    lock.SetStatus(Aws::S3::Model::ObjectLockLegalHoldStatus::ON);
    request.SetLegalHold(lock);
    auto outcome = minio_client->PutObjectLegalHold(request);
    if (!outcome.IsSuccess())
    {
        std::cout << "Error setting lock status: " << outcome.GetError().GetMessage() << std::endl;
    }

I overwrite the same file like that:
    Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectRequest in_request;
    in_request.SetBucket(bucketName);
    in_request.SetKey(manag_file_name);
    in_request.SetBody(in_stream);
    in_request.SetContentLength(in_mem_size);
    auto in_outcome = minio_client->PutObject(in_request);
    if (!in_outcome.IsSuccess())
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << in_outcome.GetError().GetMessage() << " size: " << in_mem_size << std::endl;
    }

And I am successful, even though I locked the file!
I can also delete the file via the Awssdk, ignoring the Legal Hold. But if I try to delete the file in the MinIO Console I get a WORM error:

Object, '1_1_0' is WORM protected and cannot be overwritten

So the Legal Hold is there but Awssdk kind of ignores it?

Surely the responsibility of enforcing the legal hold falls on MinIO, not the clients? File an issue with MinIO and/or reread their documentation.
